# Print the respond of a SOS service using Open layers

Tags: javascript, web-services, openlayers

I am trying to learn how to use Openlayers and the SOS (sensor observation service) service. I found several examples in internet and I studied the algorithms but since I am not very familiar with Openlayers library and I am beginner in Javascript I have some basic questions.

The example I studied is this: http://ows.terrestris.de/examples/ol-sos-layer.html

In this example they make a request to the service like this (part of the code):

```
      OpenLayers.SOSClient = OpenLayers.Class({
               url: null,
               map: null,
               capsformat: new OpenLayers.Format.SOSCapabilities(),
               obsformat: new OpenLayers.Format.SOSGetObservation(),
               initialize: function (options) {
                  OpenLayers.Util.extend(this, options);
                  var params = {'service': 'SOS', 'request': 'GetCapabilities'};
                  var paramString = OpenLayers.Util.getParameterString(params);
                  url = OpenLayers.Util.urlAppend(this.url, paramString);
                  **OpenLayers.Request.GET({url: url,
                  success: this.parseSOSCaps, scope: this});**
                  } ...
```

On success the parseSOSCaps function is executed. This function parses the XML respond:

```
            parseSOSCaps: function(response) {
                 // cache capabilities for future use
                 this.SOSCapabilities = this.capsformat.read(response.responseXML || response.responseText);
                this.layer = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("Stations", {
                     strategies: [new OpenLayers.Strategy.Fixed()],
                      protocol: new OpenLayers.Protocol.SOS({
                       formatOptions: {internalProjection: map.getProjectionObject()},
                       url: this.url,
                       fois: this.getFois()
                    })
```

Finally there is the init() function, which is executed when the page is loaded. There the url of the service, which I send the request, is declared:

```
        function init(){
                 map = new OpenLayers.Map( 'map' );
                 var baseLayer = new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS("Test Layer", "http://labs.metacarta.com/wms/vmap0?", {
                 layers: "basic"}, {singleTile: true});


                 **var sos = new OpenLayers.SOSClient({map: map, url: 'http://cawa.gfz-potsdam.de:8080/SOS/sos'});**
               }
```

My question is, how can I print/show the XML respond of the request? Is there a way that I could document.write the respond? Or even alert it? I know what I am asking might sound quite simply but I am a bit lost when I try to understand the Openlayers library and the concept of SOS service. 
Thanks.
Dimitris

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out that the variable response is an object. I can use inside the `parseSOSCaps()` function:

```
parseSOSCaps: function(response) {
    alert(response.toSource());
    ....
}
```

in order to see the respond of the SOS service.